# How to apply rotation to 3d object by device linear acceleration with gradual rotation stop in Three.js/React Three Fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

@react-three-fiber/drei has a `<OrbitControls />` component where someone can spin the camera around the main 3d object using mouse left click and it'd gradually slow down. [See this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bounds-and-makedefault-rz2g0?file=/src/App.js).

Is it possible to do something similar, except apply rotation via linear acceleration? The device rotation comes from this [hook](https://github.com/masaok/react-hook-linear-acceleration) and returns x, y, z device acceleration.

The [threejs Object3D class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D) mostly has methods to apply set the rotation, but that doesn't change the rotation overtime based on a value, it only straight up sets a rotation angle.

```
React Three Fiber Typescript (More or less same as default example, https://codesandbox.io/s/brnsm?file=/src/App.tsx)

const Box = (props: ThreeElements["mesh"]) => {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the THREE.Mesh object
  const ref = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!);
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false);
  const [clicked, click] = useState(false);

  // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
  useFrame((state, delta) => (ref.current.rotation.x += 0.01))


  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      scale={clicked ? 1.5 : 1}
      onClick={(event) => click(!clicked)}
      onPointerOver={(event) => hover(true)}
      onPointerOut={(event) => hover(false)}
    >
      <boxGeometry args={[3, 3, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? "hotpink" : "orange"} />
    </mesh>
  );
};

/**
 * Note not using numbers as title as that's a reversed parsing thing
 * @returns
 */
const ThreeD = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight />
      <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />

      <Box position={[-1.2, 0, 0]} />
    </Canvas>
  );
};
```

Would it just be getting the linear acceleration x, y, z values and then setting that as the rotation. Like

```
  Box Component

  // lAccel (x, y, z)
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    ref.current.rotation.x += lAccel.x
    ref.current.rotation.y += lAccel.y
    ref.current.rotation.z += lAccel.z
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less what's below. uses linear and device orientation to apply an additive force to the object's rotation. UseEffect as the hooks are states and auto update themselves.

```
const Box = (props: ThreeElements["mesh"]) => {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the THREE.Mesh object
  const ref = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!);
  const [hovered, hover] = useState(false);
  const [clicked, click] = useState(false);

  // Set the current object to match relative device rotation
  const deviceQuaternion = useRelativeOrientation();
  const lAccel = useLinearAccel();

  // Slow down by 20%
  const dampingFactor = 0.2;

  /**
   * Update model based on device rotation
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    // Not init yet, do nothing
    if (!lAccel || !deviceQuaternion || deviceQuaternion.length === 0) return;

    // Creates proper quaternion type from hook
    // Inverted so the model moves same direction as device
    const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
      .fromArray(deviceQuaternion)
      .invert();

    // Rotation is odd, X is actually quaternion y and Y is quaternion X.
    // Because of the invert? 
    ref.current.rotation.x += (quaternion.y + lAccel.x) * dampingFactor;
    ref.current.rotation.y += (quaternion.x + lAccel.y) * dampingFactor;
    ref.current.rotation.z += (quaternion.z) * dampingFactor;
  }, [deviceQuaternion, lAccel]);

  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
      scale={clicked ? 1.5 : 1}
      onClick={(event) => click(!clicked)}
      onPointerOver={(event) => hover(true)}
      onPointerOut={(event) => hover(false)}
    >
      {/* <boxGeometry args={[3, 3, 1]} /> */}
      <Cylinder args={[2, 2, 0.3, 30]}>
        <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? "hotpink" : "orange"} />
      </Cylinder>
    </mesh>
  );
};
```